# Vuetify Datatable

Tags: vue.js, vuetifyjs3

I would like to change the name instead of item per page and put the values ​​I want instead of 10, 20, 30, 50, ALL?
I use vue3 and vuetify 3
Here is the code :

```
 <v-data-table
 v-model:items-per-page="itemsPerPage"
  v-model="selected"
:headers="headers"
:items="outilFiltre"
:search="filtre_recherche"
@click:row="clickOutil"
item-value="name"
show-select
class="elevation-1 mb-4 pt-3 pb-3"
 >
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want is right in the [API documentation](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-data-table/#props-items-per-page).  It's these props:

[items-per-page-options](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-data-table/#props-items-per-page)

```js
{ title: string; value: number }[]
```

[items-per-page-text](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-data-table/#props-items-per-page-text)

```js
string
```

Use both of them like so:

```html
<v-data-table
    :items-per-page-options="itemsPerPageOptions"
    items-per-page-text="blahblah per page"
/>
```

```
itemsPerPageOptions: [
  { value: 6, title: '6' },
  { value: 12, title: '12' },
  { value: 24, title: '24' },
  { value: 48, title: '48' },
  { value: -1, title: 'Show All' },
],
```

[Vuetify Playground bare minimum working example](https://play.vuetifyjs.com/#eNqdV9tu2zgQ/RVCwCItEEm2LDuOkV20SPfSbYEG6FNR54GWJg4bihRI2mka+N87ulkyLapxHwyInDPDc4YzJP312Xub58F2A97CuzKQ5Zwa+GspCLna+ik11Dd0xaGYIGRxDzQFpf9cevXX0qstDH31DagbugY0d4eHmMZ4OOvnoPwcwb7MDZNiD6tjfKpmGyfLx8B3gw4rTu+LH0EDKQwVPEQ5V2FHGw51olhuSp3wPZfKkBTu6IYb8lytUEh/9boZEaLAbJRoxzWHmt6CzM5biwYOiYF0Qb7edqZ79CCitRPyTLaUb8poxDDD8etsdkZ2nSAd0DhqUePICYviFhbFTlg8b2Hx3Anzxy3s8718JG85PwR3JddVYsvsDsg+3DvQGnAnXo1HozUmUW2ZWL8+O+BBCOVsLRCtDVXGNmrcyaJcF+SOcg2W9QGe0FHQDA79bKkNoWvKpWKgz873q4JIcVQFShqzM8A/FNUUEnr976hxu15TtdIDzklhd7vfKGmAiYEAeYVwh3ivJPr/4fJnaHZvfFnrw9te7EORIyV/gCBf5HpzvJ9NirHYp5eWDdOHjRKMjlwwMWXVH87XerHQj1wKKUUPDVZFL/n/gfMnsgIq3MwnF9M+5iMX80sn82OXmvnodOYfmPmA9edkPR3P+1hHzoTPbJV72hf9pGenk/474ZQpN+loFvWRHrurZOIifexS0744nfa/eI6BWik8DAfKZNq9Ql7APbYbYs99EtimpsJ/I+fvEyAJUs+IpiJ9ZMn9QP4n9l6XGi5dEo7gnSa1d+b3m/Sj5JzlMh/I/WVv3YwCe7ppUbs32hbtZx2dzvp6kyf0wbqpDkiPes+VSWAntWnQ05M9P532f1LAUyKzlZt4POo9WiaubM+dxGeBnYKaeDw9nfk7KTYDB2I87a2RaOoq7unYnW9Hf0YDddLerrvqozLi4Crcv2a9c48z8aCDb1oKfNGXSpdeovHlvL+N8fFuTK4XYZikApEpcLZVgQATijwL8b+AYXdPbyYBniNhyrRppnxOVzoogxWRbpdihwuyrHg/+xnNrVUrQ7lynfGlh5GK8S8ovEFYqDbCsAz8VGYll7ji0pkOQGf+SslHfCtikKVXp6hcpiD8gqV+pRaXOAodFm9T/O+h8D0ECtRLFVluXVWW6UhZvdU7b3fulW6Y+JKyd/sT7iOXog==)

Comment: I tried that but it didn't work I don't understand

 <v-data-table
    v-model:items-per-page="itemsPerPage"
    v-model="selected"
    :headers="headers"
    :items="personnelFiltre"
    :search="filtre_recherche"
    :items-per-page-options="itemsPerPageOptions"
    items-per-page-text="blahblah per page"
    @click:row="clickPersonnel"
    item-value="name"
    show-select
    class="elevation-1 mb-4 pt-3 pb-3"
  >

And I put in data the data to display the values

Comment: I can't tell from just your list of props, and I'm not sure what exactly "didn't work" means. Does the table load at all? Is there an error in console? Do just the new props not work? Do some or all of the other props work? Please be as detailed as possible.  You could try debugging by just using the bare minimum props, `items`, `headers`, `items-per-page`, `items-per-page-options` and `items-per-page-text`.  See if that works, if it does, add back the other props one by one until something breaks.

Comment: I added a link in my answer with a bare minimum working example.  You could add your other props and change the data, using that as a starting point.

Comment: Thank you for your answers, I am new and French on stackoverflow so I did not ask for all inclusive but I can tell you that my datatable works perfectly only the elements that I want to modify like item per page or the pagination values ​​do not modify and I have no error in the console.